# asp.net c# create a new page and refresh routing map

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, routemagic

I am using the [routemagic](https://github.com/Haacked/RouteMagic) library and it works great.  Except when I create a new page it doesn't refresh the route map.

this is my save action:

```
 protected void lbSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //save data to database;

    //recompile the route.cs
    var assembly = BuildManager.GetCompiledAssembly("~/Config/Routes.cs");
    var registrar = assembly.CreateInstance("Routes") as IRouteRegistrar;
 }
```

in the Config/Route.cs class I have a foreach loop that ties the slug to the ID:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(events.Slug, events.Slug, "~/index.aspx?id=" + events.ID, true, new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "id", events.ID } });
```

but i still keep getting a 404 page for all new pages unless i refresh IIS..What I would need to do is add a new MapPageRoute everytime I create a new "event" to avoid the 404.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out, in case anybody else needs it:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(EventInfo.Slug, new Route(EventInfo.Slug, new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary{{ "id", EventInfo.ID }}, new PageRouteHandler("~/index.aspx?id=" + EventInfo.ID)));
```

that's what I need to call after saving the new event.